# python for save each list into some output file

Tags: python, file-io

i have already this code

```
#!usr.bin/env python
with open('honeyd.txt', 'r') as infile, open ('test.rule', 'w') as outfile:
     for line in infile:
         outfile.write('alert {} {} -> {} {}\n'.format(*line.split()))
```

this code is use to split all lines and save it into a file

my goal is to split all lines and save it into some files, as many as the line that i have in honeyd.txt. one line for one output file. if i have 3 lines, then each line much save in an output file. so i have 3 output files. if i have 10 lines, then each line much save in an output file. so i have 10 output files.

anyone can help with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're ok with sequential numbering for your filenames:

```
with open('honeyd.txt', 'r') as infile:
    for index, line in enumerate(infile, 1):
        with open('test.rule{}'.format(index), 'w') as outfile:
             outfile.write('alert {} {} -> {} {}\n'.format(*line.split()))
```

This will create files named `test.rule1`, `test.rule2`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with open('honeyd.txt') as f:
    lines = [line.strip().split() for line in f] # a list of lists
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        with open('test_{}.rule'.format(i), 'w') as f2:
            f2.write("alert {} {} -> {} {}\n".format(*lines[i]))
```